# inserted type does not match in NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, int, long-integer, nsinteger

I am facing a very wierd problem. I try to understand what is going on. 
Simply speaking, I was trying to insert a NSInteger to a NSMutableArray. keys is the NSMutableArray. key is of type NSInteger.

```
[keys insertObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: key] atIndex:insPoint];
```

In xcode console. I can see  key=(NSInteger) -1. so type is NSInteger and value is -1.  However, when I run above codes and check what is in keys. It shows  (_NSCFNumber *) long 7205759403792935. 
If I changed the code to

```
[keys insertObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: key] atIndex:insPoint];
```

It shows correctly (_NSCFNumber *) int -1.
I also tried NSLog with numberWithInt and numberWithInteger

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithInteger: key]);
NSLog(@"%@",[NSNumber numberWithInt: key]);
```

They all show -1. I also tried

```
NSInteger a=-2;
[keys insertObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: a] atIndex:insPoint];
#also have some wierd number, but it works for positive number
```

What is the problem?
Any suggestions?

Comment: what's a "wired number"? Nowadays all numbers come with built-in Wi-Fi… anyway – signed vs. unsigned representation is the key.

Comment: That is an american word for "wierd".

Comment: Will you pleas write your sample code as it is, i cant understand the scenario.

Comment: I'd like to underline that the problem seems to arise as soon as the NSNumber object has been inserted into the array. Eg. the OP's NSLog gives the correct result for an object that was not stored in an array. The problem can't be signedness, because NSInteger *is* already signed. NSUInteger is unsigned. The signed NSInteger `-1` is inserted into the array, and as far as I understand, it reads incorrectly, when dumping the array contents to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7205759403792935 is more than 32 bits.
The value is -1 as a 56 bit integer.

Comment: In order to help you finding a solution, I'd like to ask for some further information... 1: Which architecture are you building for (ARM, Intel or PowerPC) ? 2: Do you need 32-bit or 64-bit precision ? 3: Try `NSLog(@"%s", [[keys objectAtIndex:insPoint] objCType]);`